# What does DS stand for in this mathematical definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, game-theory

I am reading a book about Game Theory and have just encountered the following definition of strictly dominated strategies:

[image: definition]

Here is what I do not get:

- What does DS stand for?
- *i* denotes an arbitrary player (the amount of players goes from 1-n). Let's say that *i* represents player 1, how is this then valid to say:[odd range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do8Ck.png)? I mean, in the case that *i* denotes player 1, how can the range go from s1 to s*i*(which in this case is 1)-1 when there is no player 0?

Comment: "Dominates Strictly". That's it.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Thank you. But why would you write that? Not to sound stupid.

Comment: I have provided an answer, but you should still edit your question to use MathJax so that future readers might be able to learn from your question as well.

Answer (score 1):

(DS) is a label for that inequality. Mathematical texts usually number equations to make it easier to refer back to them later on. If you look in the text, you'll find later something like: "In equation (DS)" or some other reference to the inequality, using that notation.

The notation that includes $i-1$ assumes you know that you can't plug in 1 for $i$ there; the point is to illustrate a property for one specific element of the tuple $s_i'$ and $s_i''$.

Comment: I still do not get the second part. If you cannot plug in 1 and i is one, isn't the equation wrong? Also, why are there 4 elements in the parentheses? Shouldn't it be something like (s1,...,sn) since two is the minimum of strategies and the ... represents and arbitrary number of other strategies..

Comment: Please don't mind the typos ;-)

Comment: The point is you want strategies for other than palyer $i$. And I agree with @parcly taxel that it sands for cominated strictly because it is a strict inequality.